# Number of cycles in a random graph

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

*In an undirected random graph of 8 vertices, the probability of an edge being present between a pair of vertices in 1/2. What is the expected number of unordered cycles of length 3?*

Here's how I thought of going about it:

**Method 1**
Basically cycles  ("unordered" i am assuming to mean that the vertices can be taken in any order) of length 3 would be triangles.

Letting number of vertices = v, and no of such cycles being C

For n=3, C = 1

For n = 4, c = 4. (a square with 2 diagonal lines. 4 unique triangles).
....

For n>3, C(n) = (n-2) + (n-2)(n-3) + (n-4), generalizing.

This is because: let us start with an outside edge, and the triangles possible with that as a base. For the first edge we choose (2 vertices gone there), there are (n-2) other vertices to choose the 3rd point of triangle. So (n-2) in the first term.

Next, the last term is because the very last side we choose to base our triangles on would have its leftmost and rightmost triangles taken already by the first side we chose and its immediate predecessor.

The middle term is the product of the remaining number of edges and possible triangles.

```
      .--------.

.                   .


.                   .

      .        .
```

With the above set of 8 vertices one can trivially think it out visually. (If better diagrams are needed, I shall do the needful!). So for v=8, C(8) = 40. So, as probability of an edge is 1/2 . . .

**Method 2**  The number of triangles from n points is nC3, where C is "combination". But as half of these edges are not expected to exist . . .

I am not sure how to proceed beyond this point. Any hints in the right direction would be great. Btw its not a homework question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have nC3 possible triangles. For a triangle to appear all three edges must exist - so the probability of a specific triangle to appear is 1/8.

The expected number of triangles is then `(nC3) / 8`.

In your case, `8C3 / 8` or 7.

Comment: Hmm, does these triangles appear independent of each other? I think, having one triangle affects the probability of having more than one, they may share a common edge... But I'm not sure here.

Comment: well assuming independent events in this case is standard i guess

Comment: Dependent events affect the variance, not the expected value.

Answer (score 1):

So we have a graph with 8 vertices, now we want all three length cycles possible, given that probability of having an edge between any two vertices =1/2.

Suppose a b and c are any three vertices of given graph, now to make a cycle between a, b and c there should be an edge between a------b(probability of this=1/2) and there should be an edge between b------c(probability of this=1/2) and there should be an edge between c------a(probability of this=1/2) ,

So probability of getting one cycle = (1/2)*(1/2)*(1/2)*1 =1/8

And probability of getting all cycles=

1/8 *(total no of 3 length cycles possible with 8 vertices)

= 1/8*(8C3) =7.

Answer (score 0):

so you have given n vertices now you are having nC1 way to select the first edge.
probability  of existing that edge would be 1/2 .now in the left n-1 edge we can choose (n-1)C1 ways with probability as 1/2 similarly third edge with (n-2)C1 with probability 1/2 so simultaneously this can done as **{nC1*(1/2)*(n-1)C1*(1/2)*(n-2)C1*1/2}/3!**
we have to divide by 3!due to fact that it is asking for unordered.